# Можно ли сказать - рацион ресторана? повара?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов

> Повар этого ресторана Лучио Сфорца – из Умбрии. В его кулинарной
>   традиции несколько иное отношение к мясу и в рационе больше дичи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Соглашаясь с предыдущим оратором по поводу ответа на вопрос (уместно писать: "меню"), позволю себе несколько попутных замечаний. Формально "кулинарная традиция" относится к повару, а "меню", вполне очевидно, может относиться только к ресторану. Поэтому как минимум нужна запятая в ССП. А кроме того, не уверен, что у повара может быть некая "кулинарная традиция", впрочем у ресторана тоже. Традиция - понятие более широкое.

Comment: В том виде, в каком представлено предложение, запятой быть не может: общее  *в его*.

Comment: Если считать "его" - это ресторана, тогда "его" общее,запятая не нужна. Но формально это неверный подход. Формально следует отнести "его" к последнему, то есть к  Лучио Сфорца, а рацион - к ресторану (по смыслу). "Его" не является общим. Запятая нужна!

Answer (score 5):

> Можно ли сказать - рацион ресторана? повара?

Я бы воздержался от подобного. В таком контексте это выглядит более чем странно, чтобы не  сказать "обидно".

> РАЦИОН, -а; м. [от лат. ratio (rationis) - мера, расчёт] Порция и
>   состав пищи или корма на определённый срок. Суточный, дневной р.
>   Составить р. Р. детей, животных. Больничный, солдатский р. Ввести в
>   свой р. больше овощей. По рациону положена рыба. <Рационный, -ая, -ое.
>   Р-ая раскладка продуктов. Р. состав.

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD

Формально достаточного того, что у нас нет понятия "срока". Но дело даже не в этом. Рацион - это какие-то жесткие рамки, ***предопределенный набор*** того, что положено или предлагается съесть (а не выбрать или предложить на выбор). Для ресторана - противоестественно, он предполагает выбор. А для повара - и подавно, его рацион - это то, что он сам ест, а не то, чем других кормит.

В подобных случаях, имхо, вполне уместно слово "меню".